# CustomValidator OnServerValidate Not Working

Tags: c#, textbox, code-behind, customvalidator

I am trying to utilize a CustomValidator using the keyword "OnServerValidate"

Here is where I have it setup in my .aspx file:

```
<div class="label">
    <div><label for="parentemail1">Email Address</label></div>
    <div><asp:TextBox ID="parentemail1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" Columns="40"></asp:TextBox></div>                      
        <asp:CustomValidator id="ParentEmail1Required"
        ControlToValidate="parentemail1"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="Required"
        ValidateEmptyText="true"
        OnServerValidate="ServerValidator"
        runat="server"/>                          
</div>
```

and here is the C# code behind method for OnServerValidate:

```
protected void ServerValidator(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Am I missing something, shouldn't the CustomValidator fire when the form is submitted?
I've read through a bunch of posts and even tried this with a RequiredFieldValidator on the same control but no luck.  I have this working with ClientValidationFunction but I want to access the properties in the code behind instead of the DOM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean `ServerValidator` method is not hitting when you postback the page?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed it is firing but it is not stopping the page from redirecting to the next page.  I just noticed the form submit button code behind has this at the bottom: Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx");  Is there anyway I can stop it from doing the redirection based on the validator?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a web application and it hit the breakpoint I created in `ServerValidator`.  Sounds like you have something else going on that is not being shown in your sample code.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right Abe.  I now believe the code above is solid but the Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx"); in the form submit button code behind is what is overriding the CustomValidator.  It does the validation but before I can see it, it is pushing it to the next page. When I comment out the redirect I can see the CustomValidator error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void ServerValidator(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.IsValid == false)
       return;
    Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx");// It will not fire if page is not valid.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I like this solution. Shouldn't the validate method only validate the code? It should not be handling the redirecting. That should be handled by the submit button for the whole form. This is letting a single field's validator redirect the page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the argument args is not sent to server and that's why you don't get server message. Add a button can do this.

Change the code to

```
<div>
        <div class="label">
    <div><label for="parentemail1">Email Address</label></div>
    <div><asp:TextBox ID="parentemail1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" Columns="40"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSendData" runat="server" Text="Send Data" />
            </div>                      
        <asp:CustomValidator id="ParentEmail1Required"
        ControlToValidate="parentemail1"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="Required"
        ValidateEmptyText="true"
        OnServerValidate="ServerValidator"
        runat="server" SetFocusOnError="True"/>                          
</div>
    </div>
```